# div getting huge (height) only on mobile

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using flexislider, which is responsive, and its working fine in most resolutions. In mobile phones, the height is huge and need to scroll a big amount of white space, the slides are not autoadjusting. In a desktop, with a small browser size it works fine too. 
Does anyone know a way to "debug" in mobile? I'm driving crazy with try and error.
site is revistarteva.com.ar

I tried using a media query, putting

`overflow:auto`

in some of the classes or elements (like slide or li) but it doesn't work.

---

### Edit 1

Thanks a lot for comments, I added the chrome tool in my PC... aparently there is a

```
<div class="mobileFix"></div>
```

that is creating that space.
Is there a way to disable it? or should I try a jquery (if its possible even)?

### Edit 2

I added (in http://www.revistaarteva.com.ar/index2.aspx) 
The CSS

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_sliderName.slides {
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 900px;
        }
```

and the jquery

```
$('.mobileFix').hide();
```

But ContentPlaceHolder1_sliderName.slides shows to have height:3865px ... so there must be a jquery changed that....maybe in Flexislider?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your code here.

Comment: you can debug android-chrome output via [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tool today. The source can be viewed at www.revistaarteva.com.ar, I'll post a summay here tonight. 
Thanks for both edits!

Comment: Can you try .mobileFix { display: none } in our css if you dont want it or you can use media-queries if you just want to disable it on mobile/handheld

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it and nothing. The hide() already hideit anyway. not the ul ContentPlaceHolder1_sliderName.slides is having that fixed hight even if I set it smaller in css (must be changed later by jquery)